# PyGTK 2 GTK 2 alternative to STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR

Tags: pygtk, gtk-2

In GTK3 toolbar context style can be set to `Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR` to make it look native in Ubuntu, but in GTK2 there is no `Toolbar.get_style_context()` method and no `STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR` constant either, is there any way to accomplish this in GTK2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is a GTK 3.x feature.